# How to save registers state just before instruction call?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64

For `arbitrary` function in C, how to save registers state just before the `call` instruction?

Consider the example below (assume it's x86_64),

```c
// We don't know what the `func` is.
#define run(func) \
    do {func;} while(0)

// Say the `func` is `add` 
int64_t add(int64_t a, int64_t b) {
    return a + b
}

int main(void) {
    run(add(1, 2));
}
```

The generated assembly code in gcc may be something like,

```
main:
    push %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    movq $1, %rdi
    movq $2, %rsi

    # The question is:
    # how can we save registers like %rdi, %rsi etc. here in C code?
    call add

    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
```

Comment: Normally you don't, you keep things that need to survive a function call in call-preserved registers so they don't need to be saved around each call.  And you can't make a C compiler emit inefficient code by writing C source code.  (Of course, leaving optimization disabled like you have makes nasty code).  If you write a `main` that uses `argc` and `argv` after a call to another function, it will typically save some other call-preserved regs (like RBX and RBP or R8) to `mov` them into.  See [What are callee and caller saved registers?](//stackoverflow.com/a/56178078).

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Are you trying to learn how GCC compiles function-calls?  Or are you trying to trace function args on calls?

Comment: The reason why I want to save the registers is that I want to execute assembly instructions from `call add` in another ***running*** thread, so I need to make a copy of registers to that thread too.

Comment: For more detailed, I want to store the registers context (but no stack in this thread), and load it and run in other thread.

Comment: Instead of a CPP macro, maybe you want a C++ lambda or `std::function` that can turn anything into a callable object you could pass to another thread.  I don't think you need to use assembly language for this.  In the simplest form you could just save the args to a global variable, maybe from a wrapper function for `add`.

Comment: What _assembly instructions from `call add`_ do you mean, and how do you plan to _run in other thread_?

Comment: @Armali Save context(including %rip, which is `movq %rbp, %rsp` in this example) in the position just before instruction `call add`, and put the context to a global queue. The other threads query context from the global queue in a dead loop and restore the context and execute instructions from the %rip (`movq %rbp, %rsp`).